# Comparison of basic strengths of hydroxides of alkali metal group

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have read that $\ce{LiOH}$ is less basic than $\ce{KOH}$. But I don't know its reason. I have tried to frame a possible explanation.

**My explaination:**

I think that as $\ce{Li}$ undergoes more hydration than $\ce{K}$, $\ce{OH-}$ group will stick stronger to $\ce{Li+}$ ion. Due to this $\ce{Li+}$ will be reluctant to loose $\ce{OH-}$ and thus will be less basic. Is my explanation correct?
And, is this explanation correct for any other pair of hydroxides, ***eg***, $\ce{Sr(OH)2}$ & $\ce{Ba(OH)2}$?

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think it does -- this question is specifically asking *why* $\ce{LiOH}$ is less basic; the linked question specifically says it's **not** asking "why", but just asking for correct $\mathrmp K_\mathrm b$ values. Appropriately, all of the answers at the linked question just then provide data & references. IMO, **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is it.

To paraphrase the wikipedia article [HSAB theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSAB_theory#Modifications)

"Hard and soft (Lewis) acids and bases" (HSAB), also known as the Pearson acid-base concept, HSAB is widely used in chemistry. It assigns the terms 'hard' or 'soft', and 'acid' or 'base' to chemical species.

- 'Hard' applies to species which are small, have high charge states (the charge criterion applies mainly to acids, to a lesser extent to bases), and are weakly polarizable.
- 'Soft' applies to species which are big, have low charge states and are strongly polarizable. The concept is a way of applying the notion of orbital overlap to specific chemical cases.

Pearson evidently had revised values in the paper (which is behind a firewall):

- Pearson, Ralph G. "Absolute Electronegativity and Hardness: Application to Inorganic Chemistry." Inorganic Chemistry, volume 27, number 4, 1988, pp 734–740. https://doi.org/10.1021/ic00277a030

The data from that paper is on this webpage: http://www.knowledgedoor.com/2/elements_handbook/chemical_hardness.html

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
Ion & Chemical\ Hardness\ (eV) \\ \hline
\ce{Li+} & 2.39\\ \hline
\ce{Na+} &   2.30   \\ \hline
\ce{K+} &  1.92    \\ \hline
\ce{Rb+} & 1.85     \\ \hline
\ce{Cs+} &   1.71   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Is the trend of chemical hardness same for all other groups or are there any exceptions

Comment: @Akshat - In chemistry there are always exceptions.

Comment: Sir but is there any other explaination of the same

Comment: Other explanation is ionic character, which is increase going down on alkali metal group: $\ce{Li < Na < K ...}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its correct. 
Basic character directly proportional to degree of dissociation of OH- ions
which is inversely proportional to hydration energy.

Since hydration energy of KOH is low compared to LiOH , therefore KOH will dissociate more into K+ and OH- ions increasing the basic character